# Gparted - error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0

Tags: apt, gparted, 19.04, shared-library

**Ubuntu 19.04**

**gparted version** (0.32.0-1ubuntu1)

Running `sudo gparted` i get:

```
Unit tmp.mount does not exist, proceeding anyway.
/usr/sbin/gpartedbin: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 and I get this:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  libgtk2.0-0 is already the newest version (2.24.32-3ubuntu1).
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How Do We Fix It?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to reinstall it `sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgtk2.0-0`

Comment: Thank you for helping @Andra. Now it works.

Comment: Okay, I'll make it as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to reinstall it

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgtk2.0-0
```